# How to remove first row and last row without having identifier in Fixed length Flat file?

Tags: ssis

I have a fixed-length flat file with a header and footer, but those rows do not have any identifier like H for header, T for trailer or D for Data or something along those lines.

All my data starts with position 1, but header and footer start with different positions in the row format. I tried to use a conditional split, but I could not get the result I wanted.

Please help me to find some logic to get header and footer out of the data file. I want to store data in a SQL Server table, and header/footer data in a flat file for future reference.

Comment: You should show us what you tried, including sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not included the exact file format in the your question, let us assume the looks like this:

```
    This is the header line with some spaces at the beginning.
This, is, real, line 1
This, is, real, line 2
       End of file. It has some spaces too at the beginning.
```

If this is a correct representation of your situation, you can use a flat file source, read each record in ins entirety in one column, say EntireRow, and then use a conditional split to identify the header/footer using the following condition:

```
LEN(EntireRow) > LEN(TRIM(EntireRow))
```

The issue here would be how would you split the meaningful rows (The real lines 1 and 2 in the example above). You can dump it in another file. Now, this file will be clean with header and footer removed. This is a simple but not the most efficient solution.

Solution 2:

A better solution would be to use a Script Component. Learn about how to add a row dynamically. One such example: http://www.sqlis.com/post/The-Script-Component-as-a-Transformation.aspx

Now, to get you started, a sample code that would eliminate the header/footer using your condition that they do not start at position 1 ... with no error handling. The link above will tell you how to add the output and the columns within that output. Make sure the data types your columns match with what your source file has.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    /*
      Add your code here
    */

    if ((Row.EntireRow.Length == Row.EntireRow.Trim().Length))
    {
        string[] sArrFields = Row.EntireRow.Split(',');

        MeaningfulBuffer.AddRow();
        MeaningfulBuffer.Col1 = sArrFields[0];
        MeaningfulBuffer.Col2 = sArrFields[1];
        MeaningfulBuffer.Col3 = sArrFields[2];
        MeaningfulBuffer.Col4 = sArrFields[3];

    }
}
```

Hope this much guidance is sufficient for you to resolve your issue and one of the two solutions I have offered works. Please respond back.